# Capturing packets in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, networking, scapy

How can I capture packets with python3? I would like to emphasize that my goal is not to listen to traffic, but to capture it. For instance, the Python Scapy module has a sniff function that allows you to listen to the traffic, but not to capture it. Is there a function that allows me to capture a packet so that I can determine whether to send it or not?

Comment: If more about my question, I need to implement a switch. That is, I intercept the packet, and then decide what to do with it, depending on its Mac address and switching table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To capture traffic you just save what you sniffed.

```
from scapy.all import *
wrpcap("somefile.pcap", sniff(iface='yourInterface', count=100))
```

Comment: I need to process packets in real time. That is, I do not save the incoming package, but process it on the fly and send it on

Answer (score 0):

The best way to capture packets and not only to sniff them is by using pydivert.

```
import pydivert

# Capture only TCP packets to port 80, i.e. HTTP requests.
w = pydivert.WinDivert("tcp.DstPort == 80 and tcp.PayloadLength > 0")

w.open()  # packets will be captured from now on

packet = w.recv()  # read a single packet
print(packet)
w.send(packet)  # re-inject the packet into the network stack

w.close()  # stop capturing packets
```

This will capture all the tcp traffic on the destination port 80. You need to filter only the traffic you want to capture.
Be also aware that by doing this the performance network will may vary depending on what you are doing with the captured packets.